# SSH2 if login failed = exit. PHP

Tags: php

how would i make this code, exit or quit if the login to the ssh2 fails.

```
            $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ssh2");
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
            $ip = $row['ip'];
            $user = $row['user'];
            $pass = $row['pass'];
            $ssh = ssh2_connect($ip, 22);
            ssh2_auth_password($ssh, $user, $pass);
```

Answer (score 2):

The documentation on [`ssh2_auth_password()`](http://php.net/ssh2_auth_password) says:

> Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure.

So you can just check if it returns false

```
if(ssh2_auth_password($ssh, $user, $pass) === false) {
    //do stuff if it can't login
}
```

While you're doing that, you may also want to add some error checking to the `ssh2_connect()` call, as it can return a non-resource if it was unable to connect.

```
$ssh = ssh2_connect($ip, 22);
if($ssh === false) {
    //do stuff if it can't connect
}
```

**Edit for comment**

If you'd like to have it fallback on another login attempt, you can do it a couple of ways. If you'll just have one more set of credentials, you can simply duplicate the `if` inside of itself.

```
//try the first login
if(ssh2_auth_password($ssh, $user, $pass) === false) {
    //try the second set
    if(ssh2_auth_password($ssh, $user2, $pass2) === false) {
        //do stuff if it can't login
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if you have a large number of credentials to try, you can store them in an array and loop over it

```
$creds = array(
    array('user' => $user, 'pass' => $pass),
    array('user' => $user2, 'pass' => $pass2),
    //etc
);

$logged_in = false;
foreach($creds as $cred) {
    if(ssh2_auth_password($ssh, $cred['user'], $cred['pass'])) {
        $logged_in = true;
        break;
    }
}

if(!$logged_in) {
    //do stuff when you can't login
}
```

Comment: ok  this code works any way i can make it so when it fails it will skip it and use a different ssh2 login

Comment: Edited my answer. Don't forget to mark the accept the answer if it did answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use exceptions for things like this:

```
try {
    if (!$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ssh2")) {
        throw new Exception("MySQL query failed.");
    }
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
        $ip = $row['ip'];
        $user = $row['user'];
        $pass = $row['pass'];
        $ssh = ssh2_connect($ip, 22);
        if ($ssh === false) {
            throw new Exception("Connection to $ip:22 failed");
        }
        if (ssh2_auth_password($ssh, $user, $pass) === false) {
            throw new Exception("Password failed for user '".$user."'");
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```